# Parent child with different status

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, parent-child

It's not a basic parent child hierarchy but a more sophisticated.

Here is an example of data:

```
id   parent_id   status
-----------------------
 10          10      on
 11          10     off
 12          12     off
 13          13      on
```

What I want is to have the offline data (id 11 and 12). My problem here lays on the fact that id 11 has a parent with an 'on' status, which should also be taken.

The desired result would be:

```
id   parent_id   status
-----------------------
 10          10      on
 11          10     off
 12          12     off
```

What I wrote so fare is:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1,parent_id
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t1 t11 ON t11.id = t1.parent_id
WHERE ((t1.status = 'off' AND t11.status='off') 
       OR (t1.status = 'off' AND t11.status='on'))
ORDER BY t1.parent_id, t1.id
```

With this query, I don't have rows with t1 and t11 status equal to 'on' (which are needed).

The output of this is:

```
id   parent_id   status
-----------------------
(10)        (10)    (on) -- missing row 
 11          10     off
 12          12     off
```

How to obtain the desired result (table 2)?

Comment: Why don't you just use `WHERE t1.Status = 'off'`?

Comment: Do you only need 1 level for parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but inaccurate. Try this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1,parent_id
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t1 t11 ON t1.id = t11.parent_id
WHERE t1.status = 'off' OR t11.status='off'
ORDER BY t1.parent_id, t1.id
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I wanted.